# AlloyDB: Drop database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, drop-database, google-alloydb

How could I drop an exisitng AlloyDB database programatically?

I'd like to run a test suite of our application on AlloyDB. I'm able to connect to the cluster using the proxy. However, when I try to drop database to cleanup the test environment, using code like:

```
echo "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS application_test" | psql
```

I'm getting:

```
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DROP"
 LINE 2: DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS application_test
```

I'm sure I can connect to the cluster correctly, because I run other queries before this one.

How could I remove an existing database from a script? I can't find a good way to do that in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run psql from the CLI you'll want syntax like:

```
psql -d postgresql://\<user>:\<password>@\<AlloyDB IP>:5432/postgres \
  -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS \<dbname>"
```